# return values existing in other rows based on column match

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Business_Date = c("01/01/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2020"), Business_Date_2019 = c("01/01/2019","01/01/2019","01/01/2019"), Television = c("A","B","C"))
```

And I would like to create a fourth column based which contains the Television for that specific date in 2019:

```
desired_output <- data.frame(Business_Date = c("01/01/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2020"), Business_Date_2019 = c("01/01/2019","01/01/2019","01/01/2019"), Television = c("A","B","C"),
                             Television_2019 = c("B","B","B"))
```

However, when I write:

```
df$Television_2019 <- case_when(
  df$Business_Date == df$Business_Date_2019 ~ df$Television,
  TRUE ~ NA_character)
```

It doesn't return the desired_output:

```
  Business_Date Business_Date_2019 Television Television_2019
1    01/01/2018         01/01/2019          A            <NA>
2    01/01/2019         01/01/2019          B               B
3    01/01/2020         01/01/2019          C            <NA>
```

As row 1 and row 3 also have in the second column `"01/01/2019"`, I would like to also return `"B"` in the fourth column for those rows.

How to write a script that returns the desired_output from df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating a named vector to use as a lookup table:

```r
tv_lookup <- setNames(df$Television, df$Business_Date)
df$Television_2019 <- tv_lookup[df$Business_Date_2019]

df
#   Business_Date Business_Date_2019 Television Television_2019
# 1    01/01/2018         01/01/2019          A               B
# 2    01/01/2019         01/01/2019          B               B
# 3    01/01/2020         01/01/2019          C               B
```

The reason `case_when(df$Business_Date == df$Business_Date_2019)` doesn't give you what you want is that it compares each element in `Business_Date_2019` to the element *in the same position* in `Business_Date`. With your example data, this results in:

```
"01/01/2018" == "01/01/2019"  # FALSE, therefore <NA>
"01/01/2019" == "01/01/2019"  # TRUE, therefore "B"
"01/01/2020" == "01/01/2019"  # FALSE, therefore <NA>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! However, as row 1 and row 3 also have in the second column 01/01/2019 I would like to also return there B in the fourth column. How to do that?

Comment: @Afke see my edited answer. I also took the liberty of editing your question; feel free to roll back if I didn't capture what you're asking.